# How does CPUs runs Multiple Applications at a Time with a limited number of Registers?

Tags: x86, x86-64, cpu-registers

Ok, this is very Confusing to me, Every tutorials on Assembly says there are Less number of Registers built into the CPUs, So what if i create a Program which uses registers for calculations like this:

```
global _start 

section .text

_start:

reStrt:  ; Label, Restart...

MOV ah, 0 ; Initialise ah to 0

INC ah ; ah++ [OR] ah=1

JMP reStrt ; Unconditional jump to label "reStrt"
```

After Assembling and linking this Code, with Subsystem:CONSOLE, I will Launch it, and will see the Program which never Quits.

To Close it we have to Press the [X] button of the Console window, and on the same time while this Program is running and using the Register ah to increase by 1 and decrease by 1, I launch that application Again, Now the Same program is running 2 times on the same time.

But how is this possible to do so? if AH register is one in the CPU then how two programs can Share that register but does'nt share one's Value with another? B'cause i have not even Created a Variable(label) to store the value in Memory(RAM). Also, if there are hundreds of Registers but a Application is restricted to use one copy of each, then How can i say How much Processes my Computer can Handle?

Comment: You don't need to capitalize so many words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On [context switches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch) (in particular, when running some other [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29)), the [operating system kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28operating_system%29) is saving the process state (notably inside its [scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_%28computing%29) for [preemptive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_%28computing%29) multi-tasking), notably the [registers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_register), somewhere in [memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_memory).

The hardware is able to handle [interrupts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt) often by saving at least some registers in memory.

If you used [Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux) or some other [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) operating [system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system), you'll be able to study [its](http://kernel.org/) source code and find all these details. See e.g. the [Linux Assembly HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Assembly-HOWTO/)

Please, read much more about [operating systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) and [computer architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_architecture) (including [instruction set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set) architecture). Go to a library, you'll find many books on these subjects.

Comment: That means the Kernel automaticaly saves it in the ram, and that means Programs are actually not running at the same time, the instructions are passed to Processor One by One, Not all at once. is'nt it? Thanks for your Short answer I like it!

Comment: You need to follow all the links I gave you and to spend many hours reading books on operating systems and processor architecture. And please, don't capitalize so much words: writing "to Processor One by One" is wrong, should be "to processor one by one"

Comment: Sorry, its my bad habbit, i will take care of it next time, and sure i will definitely follow your links, but it would take some time as im very busy now, And thanks for the help...